# If $\gamma$ is irrational, then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(2\pi k \gamma)\to \int_T f(t)\,dt$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I need to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(2\pi k \gamma)=\int_T f(t)\,dt.
$$

Here $\gamma$ is any irrational number on the real line and $f(t)$ is any continuous periodic function defined on $T = [-π, π]$.

I have to show this equality, but I have absolutely no idea how to approach...I can't even figure out the reason why $\gamma$ has to be irrational.

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: I have edited your question, please check that I did not change anything important. Also, could you put this into some context or show some effort, or give some tools you actually have? It will both help and motivate people to give something back to you.

Comment: You need to read up on [equidistributed sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence).

Comment: By the way, you are missing the factor of $2\pi$ somewhere; consider the constant function $f\equiv 1$.

Comment: @Yes No need for equidistributed sequences, Stone-Weierstrass to the rescue!

Comment: This is just the ergodic theorem (and the fact that irrational rotations on $S^1$ are ergodic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as pointed out in the comments above, the right hand side needs a factor of $(2\pi)^{-1}$. With that in mind, here we go.

Let's pick our favorite $2\pi$ periodic functions. Namely, for $j=0,1,2,\dots$ let $f_j(x)=e^{ijx}$ (where $i$ is the imaginary constant). Now let's see if the equality holds for these functions. For $j=0$, it is easy to see that both sides equal $1$. The hard case is $j\neq 0$. I'll leave it to you to check that the following holds for $j\neq0$:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{ijx}=0.
$$
Now consider the partial sums on the left hand side. We have 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N e^{2\pi i k\gamma j}=e^{2\pi i\gamma j}\frac{1-e^{2\pi i N\gamma j}}{N(1-e^{2\pi i\gamma j})}
$$
Let us consider 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{2\pi i N\gamma j}}{N(1-e^{2\pi i\gamma j})}
$$
As the function $e^{ijx}$ is periodic, the numerator is bounded in magnitude, as 
$$
|e^{2\pi i N\gamma j}|\leq \sup_{y\in T} |e^{ijy}|.
$$
Moreover, as $\gamma$ is irrational, $j\gamma$ is never an integer for $j=1,2,\dots$ meaning that 
$$
1-e^{2\pi i \gamma j}\neq 0.
$$
Therefore we get 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{2\pi i N\gamma j}}{N(1-e^{2\pi i\gamma j})}=0
$$
and working back through we can see that this implies 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N e^{2\pi i k\gamma j}=0
$$
as desired.

So we have shown that the identity holds for all $f_j(x)$. By linearity of the sums and integrals, we can see that it will hold for any trigonometric polynomial, i.e. any function that can be written as 
$$
\sum_{j=0}a_jf_j(x)
$$
for some scalars $a_j$. Now we are in luck, because we can approximate all continuous functions arbitrarily well using trigonometric polynomials. Can you use the Stone-Weierstrass approximation to go from here? If not, let me know and I can add a detailed follow up :)

Edit: finishing the problem.

Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $f(x)$ be an arbitrary function meeting your restrictions. Using Stone-Weierstrass, we can find a trig polynomial $g(x)$ such that 
$$
\sup_{y}|f(y)-g(y)|<\epsilon/2. 
$$
Now consider 
$$
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(2\pi k\gamma)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt\right|.
$$
Using the fact that the equality holds for our trig polynomial, this is equal to
$$
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(2\pi k\gamma)-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ng(2\pi k\gamma)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t)dt-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt\right|.
$$
Using the triangle inequality, we can bound this by 
$$
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(2\pi k\gamma)-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ng(2\pi k\gamma)\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t)dt-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt\right|,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n[f(2\pi k\gamma)-g(2\pi k\gamma)]\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)-f(t)]dt\right|.
$$
This can now be bounded by 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|f(2\pi k\gamma)-g(2\pi k\gamma)|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |g(t)-f(t)|dt
$$
which in turn is bounded by 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{y}|f(y)-g(y)|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sup_{y}|f(y)-g(y)|.
$$
By choice of our trig polynomial, this is less than 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon/2+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\epsilon/2=\epsilon.
$$

Now take $\epsilon$ to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I have just read your miraculous solution and can't think of how to proceed from what you ended. Could you please continue and show me the complete solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Merideth I have updated the proof. Let me know if I can elaborate on anything more :)

Comment: The proof above with minor modification also works for the more general:  If  $f$ is continuous in [0, 1], then

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {f(h(k\gamma ))}  = \int_0^1 {f(x)dx} $ , where  
$h(\gamma k) = \gamma k - [\gamma k]$ is the fractional part of $\gamma k$.  This problem is from a old Russian problem book.

Comment: Just like to add that, perhaps using the real trigonometric polynomial form is easier for those who prefer to stay in the real. It is easy to see that the problem is true for cosine(mt) and sine(mt) (all picking up 0 for m >1 by summing up just like the Dirichlet kernel). So approximating by trigonometric polynomial achieves the proof as above. For the general problem I stated in my previous comment. Reparametrize to $[0, 2\pi]$  use a trigonometric cosine polynomial approximation. (You can produce one via Bernstein polynomial) The rest of the proof is as above.